# Struts.config message resources java

Tags: java, struts

I am relatively new to java and google usually helps me enough to struggle through but I am having significant trouble with this. I have 2 properties files in the struts config xml file

```
< message-resources parameter="resources.ApplicationResources"/>
< message-resources parameter="resources.DatabaseProps" key="db"/ >
```

I understand if there is more than one you need a key? So, in my `DatabaseProps.properties` file I have this:

```
database=adatabase
table=atable
```

I need it so that I can get the two properties in my java file, as these two need to be changeable so i can use different databases and tables.

I am having trouble getting the string database and table into my java code. Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question yet. Please edit the question to describe how you're trying to access the resources.

Answer (score 0):

MessagesResources are available from Action subclasses using the [getResources()](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html#getResources%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

But As the [javadoc of MessageResources](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/apidocs/org/apache/struts/util/MessageResources.html) says:

> General purpose abstract class that describes an API for retrieving
>   Locale-sensitive messages from underlying resource locations of an
>   unspecified design, and optionally utilizing the MessageFormat class
>   to produce internationalized messages with parametric replacement.

MessageResources are intended to store locale-sensitive messages, not general configuration properties which have nothing to do with internationalization. BTW, Struts is a presentation framework, and the access to the database is not the business of the presentation layer, but the business of the persistence layer.

You should not store database configuration options into Struts message resources, but inside a properties file, loaded with the `java.util.Properties.load()` method, by some class of the persistence layer.